# Proccess XML from Curl by current page

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have page which import XML to server and than obtain response from that server. I need proccess this reposne and append errors from it. I can't do this because the browser thinks it's displaying XML.

I am using this CURL:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->accessToken);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '/import_xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
return $data;
```

This return array, but curl set header as text/xml so when I try to append part (with JS) of array to page I get XML error.

```
Error parse XML: Mismatched tag. Expected tag: </meta>.
```

Reason is HTML doctype, which is not valid XML. How can I proccess XML from remote server without XML header and this behavior?

**Edit:**
curl return JSON, but request has header set as text/xml.

```
print_r($data);
{
"response": [
    {
        "status": "error",
        "code": 480,
        "message": "invalid_item",
        "details": "description",
        "id_item": 797
    },
    {
        "status": "error",
        "code": 480,
        "message": "invalid_item",
        "details": "description2",
        "id_item": 797
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

}

[image]

Comment: Sorry it's unclear where the XML comes in . You appear to treat the response from cURL as JSON. Although the URL is `/import_xml` - does it actually return XML? If so then why are you trying to treat it like JSON? It would perhaps help if you show a) the raw response from cURL (before you json_encode it) and b) the JS part of this code which causes the actual error. The situation is unclear based on the information you've provided so far. Try to give us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Comment: if you are getting XML, why are you running it through json_decode? show us the actual data returned by `curl_exec()`, and we might be able to help you parse it properly

Comment: @Adyson URL import_xml return json, but has header as XML

Comment: @hanshenrik I changed my question about other information

Comment: What is the screenshot showing exactly? It seems to be from your browser...if so then that header is the response header from your PHP code, not from the cURL request. So you should be able to modify that to `application/json`. It would still be helpful though to see the JS code where you call the PHP URL and how it comes to show the error.

Comment: I do not call CURL via JS. JS just append format errors to page. But errors is appeared before that. I do not know which info do you want. It is simple. Form send data via CURL to server and response in JSON has header text/xml. In this point JS (which is now commented) append format errors and page is not redirected. So not redirected page has bad header and show error which is in my question.

Comment: No it's not that simple. A form doesn't "send via cURL", that's not really how it works. Your form sends a HTTP request to **your** server. Your server's PHP code then makes another HTTP request (using cURL to generate it) to the `/import_xml` URL. Your code then gets the response back from that URL, decodes it as JSON and returns it. There is no redirecting, and from what you've shown, there shouldn't be. Also it's unclear what the problem with headers is - the code you've shown doesn't set any headers, so we'd expect the default text/HTML content type.

Comment: Have you missed out some PHP code which sets response headers? The headers which come back from `/import_xml` are not relevant to your web page - only the headers which come back from PHP will be used. Also you still haven't shown any Javascript so it's unclear where the XML errors are coming from, or what. The whole thing is still a mystery, and for some reason you still didn't show us the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

there's no XML in the data you posted, it's just a json with errors. to extract the errors from the json you posted, it'd be something like

```php
$response_raw=curl_exec($ch);
$response=json_decode($response_raw,true);
$extracted_errors = [];
foreach($response["response"] as $response){
    if($response["status"]==="error"){
        $extracted_errors[]=$response;
    }
}
var_export($extracted_errors);
```

Comment: Format of json response is another thing. My be my bad english will not allow me to explain it better. I solve that the response breaks the page, although I do nothing with it, because the request that the response contains changes the header and the page no longer behaves like html.